# What's the term for distributing a video something on YouTube?

Tags: single-word-requests

For some reason I'm having trouble coming up with the verb for distributing a video via YouTube or similar internet video site. By analogy with TV my instinct is to use the word "broadcast" or "telecast" but those don't seem accurate. For example:

> This event is being recorded for later _____ on YouTube.

Is there some standard word for this? Maybe "distributed" or "publicly disseminated"?

I'd like to emphasize the sent-out-from-YouTube-publicly aspect (more than the uploaded-to-YouTube part). We should clearly indicate that it's a public video, not a private one, for example.

Comment: The website user interface has the menu structure **Create > Upload video** (accessed from a camera icon). That suggests the verb used by YouTube itself is [**upload**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/upload). If you want a different word, you'll have to be clearer on the criteria for choosing it.

Comment: @JasonBassford But you can upload a video and keep it private.

Comment: @Laurel [Apparently so.](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/157177?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en). Once it's uploaded, it simply exists. Other people can view it or not based on its privacy settings. It doesn't appear as if YouTube uses any specific terminology other than **upload**. So, any other word chosen would be a generalization—or what other people, aside from YouTube, refer to it as. Using their terminology, I suppose you could say **public upload**.

Comment: YouTube doesn't "send out" videos in the sense that one might send out mail, it responds to user requests to view videos. It does send out notifications to people who have subscribed to individual channels.

Comment: It is very common to use the verb _post_ on YouTube, as in "recorded for later _posting_ on YouTube". Something can be _uploaded_ without being visible to the public, whereas _posting_ suggests that something that has been uploaded is visible.

Comment: Why do you rule out "posting" or, come to that "distributing"?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: "Post" emphasizes the path of creator-to-YouTube, not YouTube-to-viewer, which is what I want. "Distribute" I don't rule out, if others think it's common and standard.

Comment: @Daniel R. Collins Great. Why not re-phrase the Question to make that clear?

Most obviously this new information does rule out "Posting" and still, what's wrong with "distribute" - or "disseminate" or "publish"?

What's wrong with your thesauruses or search engines?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: I think that's information already in the question (last paragraph).

Comment: If you're suggesting "I'd like to emphasize the sent-out-from-YouTube-publicly aspect (more than the uploaded-to-YouTube part). We should clearly indicate that it's a public video, not a private one, for example" means much, could you re-phrase it two or three ways, at least?

Again, what's wrong with "distribute"  or "disseminate" or "publish"?

Answer (score 3):

The word I would choose is *publish*:

> [Publish a video on your YouTube Channel](https://www.streamio.com/streaming/support/publish-a-video-on-your-youtube-channel/)

You can also use the verb *post*.

(Either way, you would have to reword your sentence a little.)

Comment: I see they also use "Sharing" once in the subtitle on that linked page.

Comment: "Publishing" would fit the OP's sentence without rewording.

Answer (score 0):

Youtubing is what I have informally heard it called.

Both [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/youtube) and [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/youtube) note it as a verb in current use.

So your example sentence would be

> This event is being recorded for later Youtubing.